# Two invariants for type III factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There are two invariants for the type $III$ factor $M$, namely, $S(M)$ and $T(M)$.

When $S(M)=[0, \infty)$, $M$ is a factor of type $III_{1}$.

My question : how to determine whether $M$ is a factor of type $III_{1}$ by using the invariant $T(M)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The invariants $S(M)$ and $T(M)$ of a type III factor $M$ are only partially related.

- If $M$ is of type III$_1$, then $T(M) = \{0\}$.
- If $M$ is of type III$_\lambda$ with $\lambda \in (0,1)$, then $T(M) = (2\pi/\log \lambda) \mathbb{Z}$.
- If $M$ is of type III$_0$, then $T(M)$ ranges over a huge class of subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$, including the two previous cases.

One way to see is, is by considering the flow of weights of $M$. This is an ergodic nonsingular action $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}$ on a standard probability space $X$. Any ergodic flow appears as the flow of weights of a type III factor (and of a unique injective type III factor).

Then $T(M)$ is the group of eigenvalues of this flow $\alpha$, namely the set of all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a Borel map $u$ from $X$ to the circle $\mathbb{T}$ such that $u(\alpha_t(x)) = \exp(ist) u(x)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and a.e. $x \in X$.

On the other hand, the type is given by:

- $M$ is of type III$_1$ iff the flow of weights is the trivial action on one point.
- $M$ is of type III$_\lambda$ with $\lambda \in (0,1)$ iff the flow of weights is periodic with period $|\log \lambda|$.
- $M$ is of type III$_0$ iff the flow of weights is properly ergodic.

Comment: In Connes' paper, $T(M)$ is defined as following :$T(M)=\{t\in \Bbb R, \fbox {there exists a weight such that} \sigma_{t}^{\varphi}=1\}$. How to prove that $T(M)$ is the group of eigenvalues of the above flow $\alpha$? Would you mind recommending some papers or books on the the proof of  conclusions you mentioned? Thanks so much , Pro Vaes.

Comment: You can find this in Definitions 1.3 and 1.5, and Theorem 1.6, of Chapter XII of "Theory of Operator Algebras II" by Masamichi Takesaki.